# Is "would love to" too colloquial for a formal email?

Tags: word-choice

In a formal (**edit:** application) mail, is it too colloquial to say:

"I would love to join your group as a postdoc..."?

For me, 'like' instead of love sounds less friendly. Is this necessarily the case?

Comment: Are you accepting an invitation, are you making an application, are you responding formally to a job offer? Please give more context.

Comment: How about "I would be very happy to..."?

Comment: @Anton it's about an application

Comment: I am keen to, I am enthusiastic about, I would like to, I would very much like to etc But make sure you give a reason for saying it or it just sounds empty blandishments. Your accepted answer "would be honoured" sounds pompous and formal in a British setting and I would react adversely to it if I read it in an application.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that "love to" could be a touch too informal, though I've seen it used and accepted in formal settings. Might "I would be honored to" work?